# Plugin to display text before a post

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development

I am trying to display some text before publising post.When i add post i am getting error as

### Publishing failed

my code is

```
function adddata(){

echo "Welcome to my  post!..........";


}


add_action('new_to_publish', 'adddata');
```

It is not getting displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smraj,

try to use a filter. Use this code snippet. Place this in our theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter('the_content', 'adddata');

function adddata($content) {

$pre_post_text = 'Welcome to my  post!..........';

// only display this on single post pages
if(is_single() && !is_home()) {
  $content = $pre_post_text.$content;
}
return $content;
}
```